# How to disable inactive tab bandwidth throttling in chromium?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, flash, bandwidth, chromium

I like to open a tab with TV or radio broadcast while I work.

But as soon as I switch to another tab or window, the video starts buffering, as if chromium limited bandwidth for background tabs...

Is it possible to disable this ?

Comment: Your tabs might be discarded - see `chrome://discards/`. To disable this option:type in your address bar: `chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding` and disable it (set to `Disabled`).

Comment: I'm using chromium 55.0.2883.87 on Arch Linux, it looks like this setting is not available yet: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=650158

Comment: Actually, I read it wrong, it seems automatic tab discarding is not active on Linux at all: `Note that automatic discarding is still not available on Linux due to the lack of memory pressure subsystem on that platform.`